# Random.Next() returns always the same value

Tags: c#

I wan´t to get a random instance of an ArrayList, but my code always returns the same value.

```
public static void randomEvent(){
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int which = rnd.Next(1,events.Count);
            Debug.WriteLine("Which event: " + which);
            Debug.WriteLine("Count Events: "+ events.Count);
            ((Event) events[which-1]).write();
        }
```

The size of events.Count is 2.

Answer (score 3):

If `events.Count` is 2, then you're calling `rnd.Next(1,2)`.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) says that the first parameter is inclusive and the second parameter is exclusive. And you're returning an int. You're asking for an int x where 1 <= x < 2. So the only thing it CAN return is 1.

You should really be calling `rnd.Next(0,events.Count)` and then you only need to do `events[which]`, not `events[which-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Move `Random rnd = new Random();` outside of the `randomEvent()` method.

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();

public static void randomEvent(){
    int which = rnd.Next(1,events.Count);
    Debug.WriteLine("Which event: " + which);
    Debug.WriteLine("Count Events: "+ events.Count);
    ((Event) events[which-1]).write();
}
```

Comment: static keyword is causing issues

Comment: Note that `Random` instances aren't thread safe, so if the event could potentially be triggered from multiple threads you need a way of handling that.